# redirection to confirmation page using react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, confirmation

I am not able to redirect to the confirmation page on submitting the form. Can someone help me with this?
This is a form that I have created using react hook form library. I am a newbie in react js.. trying the first time in react. Already searched through the internet
but didn't find  anything.
Thanks in advance.

````
     date: yup.string().required(),
     amount: yup.number().positive().integer().required(),
   });

   export default function App(){
   
       const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } =  useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema)});
       const onSubmit = data => {
         //this.props.history.push('/home')
         //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
         window.location.href = '/tranfser-confirmation?from=${from}';
         console.log(data);
       }
       const watchShowRecurring = watch("recurring", false); // you can supply default value as second argument
       const watchAllFields = watch(); // when pass nothing as argument, you are watching everything
       const watchFields = watch(["recurring", "recurringType"]); // you can also target specific fields by their names
   
       const accountTo = [
         { value: 'A', name: 'A' },
         { value: 'B', name: 'B' }            
       ];
   
       const payeeList = [
         { value: 'Payee1', name: 'Payee 1' },
         { value: 'Payye 2', name: 'Payee 2' }            
       ];
   
       return(
           <div className='form-content-right'>
   
           <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='form'>
           <h1>
             Get started with us today! Transfer amount to another account.
           </h1>
   
           <div className='form-inputs'>
           <label className='form-label'>From</label>
           <select className='form-input' name="from" {...register("from")}>
           {accountTo.map((e, key) => { return <option key={key} value={e.value}>{e.name}</option>; })}
           </select>
           {errors.from && <p>{'From is required'}</p>}
           </div>
   
           <div className='form-inputs'>
           <label className='form-label'>To (If Payee is not in the list, Please add payee)</label>
           <select className='form-input' name="to" {...register("to")}>
           {payeeList.map((e, key) => { return <option key={key} value={e.value}>{e.name}</option>; })}
           </select>
           {errors.to && <p>{'To is required'}</p>}
           </div>
   
           <div className='form-inputs'>
           <label className='form-label'>Amount</label>
           <input className='form-input' type="number" placeholder="amount" name="amount" {...register("amount", { required: true })}/>
           {errors.amount && <p>{'Amount is not valid'}</p>}
           </div>
   
           <div className='form-inputs'>
           <label className='form-label'>Date</label>
           <input className='form-input' type="Date" placeholder="date" name="date" {...register("date", { required: true })}/>
           {errors.date && <p>{'Date is required'}</p>}
           </div>
   
           <div className='form-inputs'>
             <input name="recurring" type="checkbox"  id="recurring" {...register("recurring")}/>
             <label for="recurring" className="form-label">Recurring</label>
           </div>
   
           {watchShowRecurring && (
             
           <div className='form-inputs'>
           <select className='form-input' name="recurringType" {...register("recurringType")}>
             <option value="Select">--Select--</option>
             <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
             <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
             <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
             <option value="Monthly">Yearly</option>
           </select>
           </div>
           )}
   
           <button className='form-input-btn' type='submit'>
             Continue
           </button>
           </form>
           </div>
       )
   }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Refer this : [GIF with the url you are appending to redirect, Its working but I think maybe It cant find the route you are appending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI0Ca.gif)

- Use template strings in JS not ' ' because it cant access the data.from value, its directly passed as a string. use this `/tranfser-confirmation?from=${data.from}`
- Data object has its key as from , directly accessing from would not work and passing string not value would cause problem
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals You can read it here
- Redirect is working properly because if i gave window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
- This is the output: [added google url and it redirected properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGn7i.gif)
- YOu can check the routing in your react app and proper string append might help
- React Router is a good fix for routing in SPA. Because it loads only the component without page refreshing
- You can refer here: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth for your response. I am able to do redirection using windows.href but passing form values in URL is not a good solution as user might change the values. Can you help me with the way of passing react hook form values into another page. As in this case, transfer confirmation page.

Comment: You can pass the data through props, to the confirmation page. You can use React router to link a route to every page you want to display and pass the state data of form amongst them. I have written some code to simply depict it, I did not use React router but you can if you are making an application with lot of components, find it here :https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-dijkstra-t5euv?file=/src/AcceptedForm.js

Comment: For react router : refer here:   https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start